# Can I remove .00 if there are no cents in the amount using angular's currency filter?

Tags: angular

```js
budget:number=50000;
{{budget | currency:'USD':true}}
```

The above code displays the budget like this

```
$50,000.00
```

But I want it to display like this

```
$50,000
```

Comment: You would probably have to write your own custom pipe to do this, as the current pipe only allows you to set the decimals without a condition

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the [Currency Pipe docs](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe) the third option uses the same format as the [Decimal Pipe `:digitInfo`](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe)

So you can use:

```
{{budget | currency:'USD':'symbol':'1.0'}}
```

[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/GVUk5EjVUzeTetdO2jQ4?p=preview)

Edit: [Jota.Toledo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5394220/jota-toledo) pointed out that you could display the cents if they're available with

```
{{budget | currency:'USD':true:"1.0-2"}}
```

Edit: Thanks to [Abhay Naik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4428786/abhay-naik) for drawing attention to the v5 deprecated parameters.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I'm basically using for INR `{{grandTotal | currency:"&#8377; ":true:"1.0"}}`

Comment: Just an update which might help. @0mpyrdy I get this warning in the console `Warning: the currency pipe has been changed in Angular v5. The symbolDisplay option (third parameter) is now a string instead of a boolean. The accepted values are "code", "symbol" or "symbol-narrow".` and hence I request you to update the answer accordingly. Using `symbol` instead of `true` works and removes the warning. Thanks.

Comment: The problem with 1.0-2 is that if your data is 1.9, it will format it as `$1.9`.  Cents should be either displayed as two decimals or not at all, never to one decimal.

Answer (score 3):

```
{{budget| currency : 'USD' : 'symbol' : '1.0-0' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.budget = budget.toFixed(2);
```